# Update CSS upon collision

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble implementing this functionality, basically.

There's a fixed element, and when the user hits the top of the element with the viewport, I want to update the element's css. I already know the CSS to use, but I'm quite lost about detecting the collision of the screen and the said element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for more advance element detecting position, you can use [waypoint.js](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/)

Answer (score 0):

With some research, I found isInViewport.js which is everything I needed.